# How to show Empty List into Android ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, notepad, empty-list

I am currently developing application kind of notepad or Todo list. But I need to know to how to show empty list into listview, I guess android default ListView can not handle empty list view. Basically I need to show listview with no data, which I will add later, but initially the UI for listView should be empty.

Thank You!

Comment: I don't see your problem...you can perfectly populate your listview with nothing...

Comment: Yes I did.. I found something like that <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" ></ListView>
<TextView android:text="blah blah blah" android:id="@+id/android:empty" ></TextView> But it just showing blank screen with some text, I want proper list with dividers but with empty data..

Comment: If your activity extends `ListActivity`, you can declare a view with ID as `@android:id/empty` in your layout, `ListActivity` will automatically show this View if the ListView is empty and hide it otherwise.

Comment: i don't understand the problem. use a listactivity with an empty element, which will be displayed when the list is empty

Comment: @ashutosh, did you manage to get the dividers show for empty contents?

Answer (score 3):

this may helps you when there are no data in list

```
listview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
nodat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Hre nodata is Contain Empty Textview  with SetText Your String like  No Data

Comment: yeah that's the only solution if I have already set some data in my listview and the next time I get empty data to populate. It is a little awkward solution but I tried so many things and none would work except this...

Comment: Not necessarily needed to hide the `ListView`, as if it won't contain any elements it won't show anything. This assumes the `nodat` view is on top of `ListView`, eg.: in a `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

if you added the empty list into the adapter and that adapter set to listview then it will show you empty listview. after you add item to the list then you need to call notifydatasetchanged() of the adapter.

ListView as display initially empty till you add an item to the list and notify via adapter.

Note you must call method notifydatasetchanged() of an adapter when you populate the list item for add/edit/delete.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Developer Guidelines describing ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) you can easilty setup a TextViev, any other widget will be fine as well. Where you will encurage user to create ListItem.

Here is a snippet.

```
 <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="#00FF00"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

 <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="#FF0000"
           android:text="No data"/>
```